# Understanding the coding of iterations in R loop in a concrete example

Tags: r, loops

Despite the length of the pasted code, this question is likely to be very basic, and related to my difficulties with loops in `R`.

On the comments on [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/Pg0RnP1uLVc) on ARMA(1,1) processes, a commenter offers a simulation in `R`. I think that for my question it is OK to go directly to the `# Moving-average component` of the `ARMA` function:

```
ARMA = function(phi, theta, n = 100, init = 0, burn = 0)
{
  m = n + burn # Optional burn-in
  z = rnorm(m) # White noise sample

  x = init
  for (i in 2:m) # Generate the time series
  {
    # Autoregression component

    p = min(length(x), length(phi)) # Prevent out-of-bounds
    AR = sum(phi[1:p] * x[1:p])

    # Moving-average component

    q = min(i - 1, length(theta)) # Prevent out-of-bounds
    MA = sum(theta[1:q] * z[(i - 1):(i - q)])

    # Combined AR+MA component

    new = AR + MA + z[i]
    x = c(new, x) # x is built in reverse
  }

  # Truncate the burn-in
  # Re-reverse x vector
  # Return time series

  ts(rev(x[1:n]))
}

plot(ARMA(0.3, 0.2))
```

The `q = min(i - 1, length(theta))` looks like a constant to me, since no matter what the `i` iteration number is (and we start at `2` so `i - 1` is `1` and above), `i - 1` will always be equal (in the case of `1`) or greater than `length(theta)`, `theta` being a constant (hence `length(theta) = 1`). Therefore `q`, being the `min` will always be `1`.

As a result, I don't understand `sum(theta[1:q] * z[(i - 1):(i - q)])`. `z[(i - 1):(i - q)]` would be `z[(i - 1):(i - 1)]`, which is `z[i]`. `theta[1:q]` would be `theta[1]`, which make no sense since there is only one value to `theta`, unless `theta` is a vector. The fact, though, is that I can run `ARMA` with one single value of `theta`.

What am I missing?

Comment: A small example data set and the desired solution would help people help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run ARMA because n equals 100 and the loop produces 2:m (in this case 99) values. Each of 1:99 is multiplied with theta resulting in 99 different values (`MA = sum(theta[1:q] * z[(i - 1):(i - q)])`). `z[(i - 1):(i - q)])` is not equal `z[i]` but `z[i-1]` while theta has length=1.

Comment: +1 Am I correct in interpreting that `q` is going to be `1` since `length(theta)` is `1`? So `z[(i - 1):(i - q)] = z[(i - 1):(i - 1)] = z[i - 1]` as you indicated? Then what is the reason to introduce `q`?

Comment: You're right. But imagine that theta has 3 or more values, than q has more than one value during the loop as well depending on i.